# Get selected text in Safari and use it in action extension

Tags: xcode, ios8, mobile-safari, action, ios-app-extension

I'm making an action extension for safari and I need to get the selected text for use inside the extension.

Usually in iOS i use this code to get the selected text in a webview

```
selectedText.text = [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @ "window.getSelection (). toString ()"];
```

But inside the extension i don't know how can I do !

For completeness it should be an extension with IU and i've just to turn on NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount to make extension available in Safari.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Apple explains in their [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1), you need to include a JavaScript file in the extension to perform any preprocessing. The results of that preprocessing are available via `NSExtensionItem` in the extension.

A simple example of this file is included in my [iOS Extension Demo](https://github.com/atomicbird/iOS-Extension-Demo) project at GitHub and looks like this:

```
var MyPreprocessor = function() {};

MyPreprocessor.prototype = {
    run: function(arguments) {
        arguments.completionFunction({"URL": document.URL, "pageSource": document.documentElement.outerHTML, "title": document.title, "selection": window.getSelection().toString()});
    }
};

var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new MyPreprocessor;
```

That simply extracts various details about the current page and passes them to `completionFunction`. The `ExtensionPreprocessingJS` var at the end is the hook that the extension framework looks for.

In the extension you can retrieve these values in a dictionary by asking for an item of type `kUTTypePropertyList`:

```
for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList]) {
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList options:nil completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *jsDict, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSDictionary *jsPreprocessingResults = jsDict[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey];
                    // Continue with data returned from JS...
```

Comment: Great !!
Your project is incredibly comprehensive and made me solve my problem !!
Thank you so much !!

Comment: @Tom Hi, i tried to extract document.body but it does not work. I am trying to get a screenshot image. Please advise, thanks in advance.

Comment: @WilliamKu "does not work" doesn't have any information about what kind of problem(s) you're having. If you are having trouble, post a new question with some detail.

Comment: Hi @TomHarrington, my question is at [Take screenshot of host app using iOS share/action extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119727/take-screenshot-of-host-app-using-ios-share-action-extensions)

Answer (score -1):

You may need to execute a .js file for performing that operation.

I suggest you to refer this [Extension's Tutorial](http://nsnerd.co), Its almost similar to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks HarshIT for the link!
The tutorial also works very well as an extension without UI, but I'm having trouble running the js file extensions with UI, ultimately I can not set the text of a UITextView inside the extension interface !
Have you any suggestions?

Comment: On the same tutorial there is a function , "itemLoadCompletedWithPreprocessingResults"  , in that function; see line no. 25 -> the variable "text" is having the value of selected text from java script. So you can use that variable to assign in your TextView ...